# How to set write queue max size of messageProducer in Vertx 4.x

Tags: vert.x, vertx4

We want to update the Vertx from 3.x to 4.x, but we find the MessageProducer does not extend WriteStream. We want to set write queue max size of messageProducer and use the writeQueueFull() function in order to monitor our queue size, just like Vertx 3.x provided.

Question is : Does Vertx 4.x provides some methods to limit messageProducer and monitor it? THX.